# Endpoint name of JWT grant type for OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

Endpoint for the JWTs as Authorization Grants is specified in RFC 7523 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523#section-2.1 ) as `/token.oauth2` (see below). Is it a violation of RFC7523 if the endpoint is called `/token`? Can the name of `/token` be used instead?

```
     POST /token.oauth2 HTTP/1.1
     Host: as.example.com
     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

In other words, should that part of this RFC (endpoint name) be taken literally?

Does `/token.oauth2` somehow imply the endpoint name is `/oauth2/token`? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-18) describes the base of OAuth 2.0 and it never specifies any name for the endpoints, only their behaviors. The examples are not part of the specification.

Comment: Thank you. How can I verify this? Does it say anywhere?

Comment: Well I can't find any source that states this explicitly, but what makes me state this is that the spec never gives URLs to the endpoints (except in examples) and every single framework or library that implements OAuth takes parameters for the different endpoints (not only the protocol and hostname, but the full URLs). Also, every authorization service that implements OAuth specifies the URLs in their documentation which proves that it is not part of the spec. I suppose the only thing I could do to prove my point is to quote such libraries or services, which is not 100% accurate, I agree

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and actually precise answer. This is the sort of answer I needed.